# How to change my logic to print numbers in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Here my code is working fine but i need the order of elements in different order.
This is my code.

```
 <body>
    <%
        out.println("<table >");
        int apps = 9;
        double rowColumn = Math.sqrt(apps);
        for (double i = rowColumn; i > 0; i--) {
            out.println("<tr>");
            for (double j = rowColumn; j > 0; j--) {
                out.println("<td>" + apps + "</td>");
                apps--;
            }
            out.println("</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
    %>
</body>
```

It is printing values as follows:

9   8   7

6   5   4

3   2   1

But i need values as follows :

7   8   9

6   5   4

1   2   3

if apps =16 then i need out put as follows:

16  15  14  13

9   10  11  12

8   7   6   5

1   2   3   4

Could anybody guide me how to change the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, store the values in a variable and print out after the for loop:

```
<body>
<%
    out.println("<table >");
    int apps = 16;
    double rowColumn = Math.sqrt(apps);
    boolean flag = true;
    for (double i = rowColumn; i > 0; i--) {
        String rowContent = "";
        out.println("<tr>");
        if(flag) flag = false;
        else flag = true;
        for (double j = rowColumn; j > 0; j--) {
            if(flag) {
                rowContent = "<td>" + apps + "</td>" + rowContent;

            }
            else {
                rowContent =  rowContent +"<td>" + apps + "</td>";

            }
            //out.println("<td>" + apps + "</td>");
            apps--;
        }
        out.println(rowContent);
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
    out.println("</table>");
%>
</body>
```

Comment: Macro Mercuri,Its printing the same result as what my original question is printing result.Its not printing desired output.

Comment: Oh sry i didn't see that the middle row was in inverse order! Wait a minute, i update my answer.

Comment: if apps=16 check for this conditions also

Comment: Macro,your updated code is printing like this  7 9     8
4 6 5
1 3 2

Comment: for apps=9,its working fine(printing exact output 7 8 9
6 5 4
1 2 3) but when apps=16 then not printing properly (13 14 15 16
12 11 10 9
5 6 7 8
4 3 2 1) at last row it is in reverse order for apps more than 9.can you check it .

Comment: Ok, now it works fine for apps == 16, but you want sometimes increasing first row and sometimes decreasing... **depends on what?** However you can switch the flag to true or false to change first row orientation.

Comment: Now its working fine for apps=16 but failing for apps=9,could you please check with both conditions.

Comment: Macro,Thanks a lot for spending your valuable time.I got it.